# A possible way to access an object before instantiating in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I'm making a tycoon like game in Unity, the game is about robots and stuff, you have a catalogue of robots and i've been trying for a code that instantiates the robots but you can get two of the same robot, the idea is that if i instantiated robot#1 i can't instantiate it more. I tried with a code but don't quite work.

```
 if (position == 1)
    {
        robot1 = Resources.Load ("Prefabs/Robots/" + theRobo.identifier, typeof (GameObject)) as GameObject;
        Instantiate(effect, spawnPosition1.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(robot1, spawnPosition1.position, Quaternion.identity);
        finder1 = GameObject.Find(theRobo.recognizer);

        if (finder1.GetComponent<RobotBehaviour>().created == false)
        {
            finder1.GetComponent<RobotBehaviour>().created = true;
        }

        else
        {
            finder1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            finder1.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

The "position" variable is the position of the robot, the "robot1" is the robot identifier, the "finder1" finds the "Robot(Clone)" object when instantiated, the main problem is that the code always instantiate even if it's "created", this code is repeated 6 times due to the six positions in the game. I also treid accessing the prefab directly but it changes it forever.

Pls help

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

## You can't.

You will need to find some other way of figuring out how to store the data you need to access.

Some examples:

- Make the field you want to access `static` (there will only ever be one "copy"  of that value everywhere, accessible all the time from anywhere)
- Store the data in a different place (such as in the class your code is in)
- Keep a reference to the object already spawned; You should never use `GameObject.Find()` in the first place.

Secondly, this line:

```
if (finder1.GetComponent<RobotBehaviour>().created == false)
```

Runs after this line:

```
Instantiate(robot1, spawnPosition1.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Meaning that you're creating a clone before you know if you *should* make a clone (and you're not destroying it if its not needed).

Comment: Oh yes i know that, but consideer that i have more than one finder and more than one position, what the actual code makes is, for example, i instantiate on position 1 the robot 1, then i instantiate robot 1 but on position 2, the robot on the position 1 "disappears" and now it's on position 2

Comment: That would not be *instantiation* that would be *movement.* Simply set the existing robot's position to the new values.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list/counter containing all the robots of the type. And then it is a simple numeric check:

```
if(currentRobotsTypeX >= maxRobotsTypeX)
  //error message
else
  //spawn robot of type X
```

How you manage taht list/counter is up to you. Just do not forget to remove things from the List/decrement the Counter as they leave the game. Or if the game is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static variable, acting as a counter and increment it in the constructor. After, you can check if the variable is above a desired amount and based on that you could have a callback method that either removes the object or doesn't.